# Resize a JFrame, which has no border, using a mouse

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Java desktop application using `javax.swing`.
I want make my application border-less and at the same time resizeable.
When I remove the border using the `frame.setUndecorated(true);` method I can no longer resize the frame using mouse clicks and drags.

How can I hide the border of the frame and still let the user resize it?

Comment: Add (minimal) code that you are using. state your desired behavior and observed behavior.

Comment: Given a user would typically not realize that a frame with no border **can** be resized, I think this is largely pointless.  How about you focus your efforts into *making a **usable** GUI?*

Comment: BTW - Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, welcome to StackOverflow, we have very high question and answer standards, to ensure the quality of its content remains high, as a new member it can be a bit daunting but please know that any comments like those above are advice, not criticisms, and that **all** users have in the past fallen short of the high standards posed by this site. A _"Don't worry about it, just do better next time"_ attitude is the key to doing well here!

Answer (score 2):

Frames allow a user to interact with the `JFrame` using their mouse. If you remove the frame then you cannot use it to move or resize the frame. You **can** reimplement this functionality yourself *(not sure why you'd want to but of course experimenting is always fun!)*.

First you must somehow get user mouse events. By creating a custom `JComponent`, maybe called `ResizeGrip`, and placing it in the bottom right of your frame you can visually show your user that they can still resize the frame. You can then implement a `MouseListener` to see when the user has clicked and dragged your `ResizeGrip`.

Then you need to turn those event detections into instructions to resize the frame pragmatically, that is via `someJFrame.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);`. You will also need to do something similar if you want to move the frame.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Resizing Component](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) for a general purpose class that will allow you to resize any component.

The class is a `MouseListener` that installs itself on the components you specify.

The basic code to add it to your frame would be:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
frame.setUndecorated(true);

ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
cr.registerComponent(frame);
```

You can control which sides can be dragged by specifying the "drag insets". The default value is 5 for all sides which means you can resize any size. You could limit the frame to be resized only horizontally by using:

```
cr.setDragInsets( new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5) );
```

Comment: can I remove title bar or make border thin ?

Comment: What are you talking about, your question state you already have removed the border and title bar???